# How to set the value of the multiple input field from function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, field

I can set or send value to the input field after some function. I can display my value instead of placeholder after doing some action as i need. 
It is working only for a single input filed, so how I can  do it for two or more input field (input type is text) ? 
Working code is below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input:text").val("Glenn Quagmire");

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="entername"></p>


<button>Set the value of the input field</button>

</body>
</html>
```

In this way I want to set the values  for two input field after clicking button. How can i make it functional ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("input:text").val("Glenn Quagmire");
        $("input.text").val("Kathmandu");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="entername"></p>
<p>Add : <input type="text" name="add" placeholder="address"></p>

<button>Set the value of the input field</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should be added in `user` and `add`?

Comment: loop all texts with `$("input.text").each(function () { //stuff });` though you need proper handling if you don't want all inputs contain the same values.

Comment: This would set the user: `$('input[name="user"]').val('my_user');`

Comment: It's Working !! Thank you very  much  @Mehdi Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set values for different input fields by using their name property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('input[name="user"]').val("Glenn Quagmire");
        $('input[name="add"]').val("Kathmandu");
    });
});
```